# HTML Font and Bold not rendering in IE 11 , but works in chrome - dynamically from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have code in which it renders just fine in Chrome, but in IE 11 it doesn't show up

**Problem in IE 11 - developer tools F12**

```
<li><ul>11/25/15 : <a href="http://server1/coc-home/#/tips/2?paginatePage=1" target="_parent">Dev Test in Supervisor Title</a> By: CBOWER</ul></li>
```

Works in Chrome  - developer tools F12 output

```
<li><ul>11/25/15 : <font color="red"><b>NEW - </b></font><a target="_parent" href="http://server1/coc-home/#/tips/2?paginatePage=1">Dev Test in Supervisor Title</a> By: CBOWER</ul></li>
```

So basically in IE 11 browser, the javascript is completely NOT rendering the font and bold

```
<font color="red"><b>NEW - </b></font>   -- missing in IE rendering
```

My Javascript Loop the code that renders in Chrome

```
//add red New if date created last 10 days
var dt = new Date(formattedDateString);
var today = new Date();
var newText = "";
var dateDiffDays = Math.ceil((Math.ceil(dt.getTime() - today.getTime())) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

if (dateDiffDays >= -10 && dateDiffDays <= 10) {
   console.log('NEW - date within 10 days');
   newText = "<font color='red'><b>NEW - </b></font>";
} else {
   console.log('OLD');
   newText = "";
}

strResult += "<li><ul>" + formattedDateString + " : " + newText + "<a target='_parent' href='http://" + dochomenotlocal + "/doc-home/#/tips/2?paginatePage=1'>" + news.title + "</a> By: " + news.createdby + "</ul></li>";
```

**Update:**

This Fiddle shows that it renders the javascript and css just fine in IE 11

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/yr009hwd/1/

Comment: Do not use a font tag...It has been deprecated for years.

Comment: @epascarello  - sure I know to be using css, but it that the reason IE is not showing it?

Comment: No it is not, the reason is your html you are generated is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you are generating is invalid

```
<li><ul>text
```

The UL needs to have an li as a child, you have textNodes and other elements.

Comment: I reversed the order to be  <ul><li>text</li></ul>   if that is what you mean,  but that did not work ,  IE still shows  <ul><li>11/25/15 : <a href="http://....">Dev Test in Supervisor Title </a> By: dddd</li></ul>

Comment: I did go ahead earlier and created a css class and then I am using that which works in chrome      newText = "<span class='redbold'>NEW - </span>";

Comment: Thought maybe IE 11 was not evaluating the Date object the same way , so based on my earlier created code in jsfiddle i try it in IE , and it works in chrome, FF and IE 11  just fine      http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/yr009hwd/

Comment: Good catch on the html